# prop.table with multiple variable

Tags: r, survey, surveymonkey

I'm looking to recreate a table that is populated by SurveyMonkey (example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MyV1.jpg) - along the left-hand side are the questions (e.g. How important is Factor X?) and then the discrete variable is always the same: Not At All, Slightly...etc.

What is the best way to take data that is in the format(column #s are questions and end in the resulting prop.table?:

```
            Q1        Q2        Q3        Q4
         Very       Very       Very Moderately
   Moderately   Slightly  Extremely Moderately
   Not at all       Very       Very   Slightly
   Not at all Moderately Not at all Not at all
    Extremely  Extremely  Extremely  Extremely
     Slightly       Very  Extremely   Slightly
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin, so I don't have one. If you have any suggestions based on the screenshot and sample data above, feel free to help.

Comment: @Shekeine can you stop spamming new questions and be helpful instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tidy your data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) first. Assuming your original dataset is in a `data.frame` called `df`:

```
library(tidyr)

df.tidy <- gather(df, question, result)

prop.table(table(df.tidy$question, df.tidy$result))
#     Extremely Moderately Not at all   Slightly       Very
# Q1 0.04166667 0.04166667 0.08333333 0.04166667 0.04166667
# Q2 0.04166667 0.04166667 0.00000000 0.04166667 0.12500000
# Q3 0.12500000 0.00000000 0.04166667 0.00000000 0.08333333
# Q4 0.04166667 0.08333333 0.04166667 0.08333333 0.00000000
```

---

```
# Additional stuff to look at to check your understanding...
#
# df.tidy
# table(df.tidy$question, df.tidy$result)
# prop.table(table(df.tidy$question, df.tidy$result), margin = 1)
# prop.table(table(df.tidy$question, df.tidy$result), margin = 2)
```

If you need "by-question" percentages, you will want to use `margin = 1` in the call to `prop.table()` -- see `?prop.table`

Comment: Would this be similar to melting the data together and making the able off of that?

Comment: Yes, very similar: see [this blog post](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/).

Comment: The third line could also just be `prop.table(table(df.tidy))`